# How to write and display automatically a text in an input window of a website

Tags: javascript, express

I created a website with an input window.
When I write something in the window and reload the page, the text is displayed in the window again.

My problem is that my code saves the text. After that I get the JSON answer and have to go back and reload the page.

I want to adjust that,so that it stays on the page and display the new text directly.

this is my text.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const text = require('../../Texts');

// Create text
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const newText = {
    ...req.body
  };

  text.push(newText);
  res.json(text);
  // res.redirect('/');
});


module.exports = router;
```

this is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const text = require('./Texts');

const app = express();

// Init middleware

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Homepage Route
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Text T-App',
    text: text
  })
);

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// API Routes
app.use('/api/texts', require('./routes/api/texts'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

I have another Text.js, not in the same folder as the other one and it contains only this:

```
const text = [
  {
      text: ' testing '
  }
];

module.exports = text;
```